# Alternative to Android AsyncTask

Tags: android, exception, background, android-asynctask, threadpool

I have a UI widget where I need to map addresses to corresponding contact names and display them in a given format.
I use AsyncTask to perform the query to lookup the address in doInbackground() and display the name format on the widget in onPostExecute().
This works fine when there is a limit on the addresses. 
But when number of addresses to be mapped increase..in the order of 150, I get RejectedExecutionException. 
I understand that this is because maxPoolsize is 128 and queue is bounded to 10 for AsyncTask.
I tried making the queue unbounded...but adding of names on the widget becomes very slow. That is because with  unbounded queue maxPoolSize is ignored and at a time I can have only corePoolSize threads i.e 5.

So, I wanted to know if there is any alternative other than AsyncTask that I can use for this use-case??
Cloning AsyncTask & increasing core/max pool sizes does not seem to be good behavior as that would mean many simultaneous threads(ineffective resource usage) & scheduling overhead. 
There is currently no limit on the addresses, and hence it could easily goto more than 500.
How should I handle such cases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to divide the mapping of this approximately 500 addresses in smaller parts of around 80 and then use a separate AsyncTask for every part.

Another alternative I would recommend is to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that does this work for you.

Comment: That would mean till the 80 addresses are not resolved i.e queried, there will be no update on the UI.... How can Service be used for this scenario?